# How to put a const in the main scope who depends of a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm working with next-auth and I want to use [unstable_getserversession](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#unstable_getserversession). The doc say I must import options from an another file

```js
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
```

I can't achieve this :/

The file is [here](https://github.com/spruceid/siwe-next-auth-example/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts)

Check the comments for understanding my problem. I need to put this providers const in the main scope to export the options

What is the way to do this ?

```js
export default async function auth(req: any, res: any) {
  const providers = [             // I don't know how to get this const outside of the auth()
    CredentialsProvider({         // scope, because it contain...
      name: "Ethereum",
      credentials: {
        message: {
          label: "Message",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "0x0",
        },
        signature: {
          label: "Signature",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "0x0",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {        // this function ...
        try {
          const siwe = new SiweMessage(JSON.parse(credentials?.message || "{}"))
          const nextAuthUrl = new URL(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL)

          const result = await siwe.verify({
            signature: credentials?.signature || "",
            domain: nextAuthUrl.host,
            nonce: await getCsrfToken({ req }),   // doing this call, with the "req"
          })                                      // parameter, given by auth()
                                                  // at the first line :/
```

Comment: Just write a function that constructs the `authOptions` depending on `req` and `res`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
let providers; <-----------

export default async function auth(req: any, res: any) {
  providers = [             // I don't know how to get this const outside of the auth()
    CredentialsProvider({         // scope, because it contain...
      name: "Ethereum",
      credentials: {
        message: {
          label: "Message",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "0x0",
        },
        signature: {
          label: "Signature",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "0x0",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {        // this function ...
        try {
          const siwe = new SiweMessage(JSON.parse(credentials?.message || "{}"))
          const nextAuthUrl = new URL(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL)

          const result = await siwe.verify({
            signature: credentials?.signature || "",
            domain: nextAuthUrl.host,
            nonce: await getCsrfToken({ req }),   // doing this call, with the "req"
          })                                      // parameter, given by auth()
                                                  // at the first line :/
```

Comment: Thx so much guy. I understand better now why someone downvoted me :/ I've started learning seriously web2/3 since july and I haven't yet grasp some patterns like this... Seems so obvious right now ! And I've struggled many hours on this :/

Comment: Don't do this! The module exports would change every time the `auth` function is called. Worse, you might mutate the module-level `providers` array every time, and you might be using a provider that is linked to some arbitrary http request/response.

Comment: Yeah. It will just change everytime without changing anything in auth. Just  re-assign same value to variable. Nothing dangerous if he will only read this variable.

Comment: He can also just use return to get that value if he need. He must call function anyway to get variable so return probably will be better to have properly set req and res.